# How do I add a key to a multidimensional array in AutoHotkey?

Tags: arrays, autohotkey

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in AHK. The `callback` in the key in the `Messages` array. All these handlers are executed by a Menu. I instance the Object to the Array here:

```
Application = { Messages: [] }
```

I then ask the user for a callback to use, ie: rules. The user then adds a message to the rules array.

```
CreateMessageHandler:
InputBox callback, Create a message group., Choose a callback for this message., ,
if !ErrorLevel
    InputBox message, Add a new sentence., Enter your line to store., ,
    if !ErrorLevel
        Application.Messages[callback].Insert(message)
        MsgBox Bravo! Message added successfully.`n`nNote: You can use CTRL+D to quickly display these.
return
```

To then output the callback, I ask the user for the callback he put before and then cycle through the messages and output:

```
DisplayMessageHandler:
InputBox, callback, Display a set of messages., Enter which callback you want to display., ,
if !ErrorLevel
    for key, value in Application.Messages[callback] {
        send {Raw}%value%
        send {Enter}
        sleep, 1000
    }
return
```

I am receiving no errors, I can not think how to debug the `Application.Messages` because it is not saving the callback/message to it. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

[P.S - This is my reference to information / documentation.](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The code above is trying to insert the message to an unset array, I created a separate flag like this:

```
GroupMessageHandler:
InputBox callback, Create a message group., Choose a callback for this message., ,
if !ErrorLevel
    Application.Messages[callback] := []
    MsgBox % "Successfully added " . callback ". You can how add messages to it!"
return
```

So now to add a message, you choose the callback and message and it can `Insert` the message to that array. Only limitation is I'm unsure to see if the callback exists or is a type array. I'll look into it. Thanks anyway.

Or more simply, I changed it so it created the instance of the array if it did not exist when the user was stating the group to use. I also added removal of white space because you can't have spaces in keys.

```
CreateMessageHandler:
InputBox callback, Which group are you adding., Please enter a callback so you can add more messages to this group., ,
if !ErrorLevel
    StringReplace , callback, callback, %A_Space%,,All
    if(!Application.Messages[callback])
        Application.Messages[callback] := []
    InputBox message, Add a new sentence., Enter your line to store., ,
    if !ErrorLevel
        Application.Messages[callback].Insert(message)
        MsgBox Bravo! Message added successfully.`n`nNote: All white spaces of %callback% was removed.`nNote: You can use CTRL+D to quickly display these.
return
```

I just looped through the display, nothing has really changed here apart from the white space stripping:

```
DisplayMessageHandler:
InputBox, callback, Display a set of messages., Enter which callback you want to display., ,
StringReplace , callback, callback, %A_Space%,,All
for key, value in Application.Messages[callback] {
    send {Raw}%value%
    send {Enter}
    sleep, 1000
}
return
```